# Make package for Android

Tags: java, android, c, native-code

### *Problem Description*

I'm writing module for ***Android (JAVA)*** that use ***native code (C)***. In ***JAVA*** I have created Class ***"MyClass.java"*** and implement all functions and classes there, also I call loadLibrary function from that file.

Now I want to build something like dll in C only for Android JAVA in order to give it to other users and they can use my class and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a library project that contains your Java and C stuff.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Do you want it to be used at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Okay ... Now I will check your post and tell you

Comment: And how I can create that library ?

Comment: depends if you use either eclipse or ant... there are step by step descriptions on d.android.com

Comment: I am using Eclipse ... Can you give me url ?

Comment: Sorry and how I can run my library project ?

Comment: I want to know how I can run that library ??? Because when I try "Could not find DSM_Library.apk!" error appears !

Comment: Android libraries can not run